# leaflet button inside-marker doesn't work

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, geojson, marker

i have a problem in showing a modal with a button that i have placed in a marker message, here is my code, all function well but not this button,
my controller.js

```
 **$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addLocation.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
        });**


// Get the ouvrage geojson data from a JSON
        $http.get("js/ouvrage/ouvrage.json").success(function(data, status) {
            angular.extend($scope, {
                geojson: {
                    data: data,
                    style: {
                        weight: 2,
                        opacity: 1,
                        color: 'green',
                        dashArray: '3',
                        fillOpacity: 0
                    },

                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 350};
                    layer.bindPopup(

                   '<h5><b>Informations sur l"ouvrage : </b></h5>'+
                      "<b>Groupe:</b> " + feature.properties.groupe +
                        "<br><b>Famille   : </b>" + feature.properties.id_famille +
                        "<br><b>Ouvrage   : </b>" + feature.properties.nom_ouvrag +
                        "<br><b>Projet    : </b>" + feature.properties.projet +
                        "<br><b>Nombre d'élements: </b>" + feature.properties.nbre_element +
                        "<br>"+
                        '**<button class="button button-primary" ng-click="modal.show();">Confirm</button>**'

                        ,popupOptions);
                    }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please take a bit more care formatting your code example and removing unnecessary lines from it. That'll maybe help to get an answer to your question.

Comment: Hello @Jieter and thank you for ur help, but which line i should remove ?

Comment: I don't think you need all the text in the popup to show your problem...